# set upstream on a repo

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I added libgit2sharp to my project in order to pull files from gitlab into a computer but when i try to pull (after cloning the repository of course) i get the following exception:

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: 'There is no tracking information for the current branch.'
```

i tried everything available on the web but i can't seem to solve the problem. i found out i need to set a branch as an upstream in order to solve the issue.

my question is; do i need to setup 'origin\master' as an upstream? and if so, how do i do that?

if you can add code that will help me tremendously as i am new to libgit2sharp.

Comment: Have you tried `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master`?

Comment: i did manually and it did fix the issue. the problem is that i can't seem to find a working code to do it without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

> i did manually and it did fix the issue. the problem is that i can't seem to find a working code to do it without user intervention.

If, through code, you have the name of the current branch, you need to follow one of the examples in [`LibGit2Sharp.Tests/BranchFixture.cs#CanSetTrackedBranch`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/a4c6c4552b24590995c221304e7d7c75c181ea82/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/BranchFixture.cs#L574-L603) in order to set an upstream branch.

```
repo.Branches.Update( branch,
                      b => b.TrackedBranch = trackedBranch.CanonicalName );
```

That would:

- not depend on the user
- avoid the exception message.